# Window.open() reference blocked in IE11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11, twitter-oauth

I'm implementing **Twitter OAuth** sign in in my web app. I'm doing this in a separate window popup, since I read that `IFrame` is no longer allowed in `OAuth`. So, as soon I open a new window on Twitter domain, IE sets `twitterWindow` reference to **null**. This is due to IE's aggressive Internet zone security settings, which I can't ask from users to disable.

`var twitterWindow = window.open(twitterUrl, "TwitterLoginPopup", "width=600, height=600");`

When Twitter redirects window back to my domain (after successful or failed authentication), I can see window again and handle the results. But use-case that troubles me is **when user closes the window manually** and since I don't have its reference, I can't handle that closure.

I tried to implement `postMessage()` communication between application and window, but that's also impossible without window reference. Does anybody have any workaround for this or idea for different implementation of the `OAuth`? Thanks in advance.